# how to use route test kit to test routes

Tags: java, scala, playframework, akka, akka-http

Hi I want to perform end to end testing I have a play application in Which I have controllers I want to test the routes with Akka route test kit 
I am following this link

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/testkit.html

I want to ask how can I test this route with akka http route test kit

```
POST    /getuserid                  controllers.UserController.getUserID()
```

here is the Action method

```
class UserController extends Controller {
def getUserID = Action { implicit request =>
    var jsonResponse = Json.obj()
      var jsonRequest = request.body.asJson.get
      val id = (jsonRequest \ "uuid").as[String]
      Ok("id is "+id)
  }
}
```

here in the link its written

> ROUTE is an expression evaluating to a Route. You can specify one inline or simply refer to the route structure defined in your service.

how can I achieve -> simply refer to the route structure defined in your service 
Please help

Answer (score 0):

While the Play Framework does use Akka-Http as the implementation for the server, the high-level API is Play's, not Akka's, so you don't build `Route`s, but `Action`s and so you can't use the Route test-kit.

To test Play Framework controllers, see [Unit Testing Controllers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTestingWithScalaTest#unit-testing-controllers) in the docs.

Comment: so there is no way to call Actions in test it using akka test kit ?

Comment: No, but testing actions is simple enough directly.